# why do not we connect inductor in dc circuits. And what are the physical significance of connecting a capacitor or inductor in a circuit

Tags: inductor

Why doest an inductor not connected in a dc circuit? What happens? And why it is connected in ac circuits? Explain one more thing that why do we need to connect an inductor or capacitor in a circuit. What is its physical significance, means i want to know that what type of changes it brings when it is connected and what are the use of that changes in that very circuit.

Comment: Of course inductors are used in DC circuits - if the circuit is dominated by the DC component of current, the circuit is said to be DC despite having an "alternating" effect on the DC.

Comment: I think it's been downvoted because the question is not clear. But it's mainly because of grammar. If the OP can't make it clearer in my opinion we should edit it instead of downvoting. Still, it's a bit too broad, most of it could be answered by looking around on the web. After reading elsewhere, what don't you understand exactly?

Comment: I voted to close because it is way too broad.

Comment: I agree with Wouter. Had OP stopped after the first three questions this would perhaps be answerable despite the grammar. With the addition of "explain one more thing" this question goes in a completely different direction.

Answer (score 1):

Inductors are just a coil of wire - in a DC circuit they do nothing. In an AC circuit the inductor acts like a resistor, the resistance changes with the frequency.

Capacitors are the opposite. In a DC circuit they block current. In an AC circuit the "resistance" decreases with frequency.

Comment: I would add that since the resistance changes with frequency, the transients (response to any other signal other than DC or AC sine) are also different when compared with resistors (duality frequency/time domain).

Comment: Your answer assumes that the inductor or capacitor is in series with a load. If in parallel the inductor does soething altogether different to how you describe and that capacitor "do(es) nothing"

Comment: @Andyaka An inductor in parallel in a DC circuit will short it out, releasing the Magic Smoke™. A capacitor in parallel with a light bulb won't do much either. I have basically written my answer to match the questioner's English and electronics knowledge level, leaving out those details that would just add a lot of confusion.